# Não consigo atualizar o valor de uma String ao clicar num determinado botão

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick

Estou fazendo um projeto de uma calculadora e não estou conseguindo atualizar a tela quando alguém tecla o número 7, por exemplo. Eis o código:

**HTML:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
 <body>
   <div class="py-0 text-center w-25"><div class="container">
       <form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
   </div></div>
    <div class="py-0 text-center w-25"><div class="container">
      <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-danger">AC</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-danger">c</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-primary">/</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-primary ">x</div>
  </div></div></div><div class="py-0 text-center w-25"><div class="container"><div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-primary" onclick="handlers.addTecla('7')">7</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-primary">8</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-primary">9</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-primary">-</div>
  </div></div></div><div class="py-0 text-center w-25"><div class="container"><div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-primary">4</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-primary">5</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-primary">6</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-primary">+</div>
  </div></div></div><div class="py-0 text-center w-25"><div class="container"><div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 w-25 btn btn-primary">1</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-primary">2</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-primary">3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-primary">=</div>
  </div></div></div>
  <div class="py-0 text-center w-25"><div class="container"><div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-primary">%</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-primary">0</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-primary">.</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 btn btn-primary">LN</div>
  </div></div></div> 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
.col-md-3{
  max-width: 50px;
  margin: 1px;
}
.col-md-12{
  max-width: 206px;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var model = {
    tela: [""],
    addTecla: function(tecla){
        this.tela.push(tecla);
    },

var handlers = {
    addTecla: function(tecla){
        model.addTecla(tecla);
        view.displayTela;
    }
}

var view = {
    displayTela: function(){
        var pTela = document.getElementById('tela');
    pTela.innerHTML = '';
        var tela = model.tela.join('');
        pTela.innerHTML = tela;
    }
}
```

Link no codepen: https://codepen.io/LucasNavarro/pen/JOMEmz

Comment: Lucas, tente colocar sempre um [mcve] aqui do código e não apenas a parte que julgar importante, porque pode ser que o problema está na parte que você não colocou aqui, como foi o caso agora. O link do codepen é legal, mas como um extra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu HTML, faltou dar o `id` "tela" ao `input`:

```
<input id="tela" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
```

No seu JavaScript, você tinha colocado uma vírgula no lugar do fecha chaves entre o objeto `model` e o objeto `handlers`. Além disso, você estava fazendo `view.displayTela` em vez de chamar a função fazendo `view.displayTela()`. Consertando, fica assim:

```
var model = {
    tela: [""],
    addTecla: function(tecla){
        this.tela.push(tecla);
    }
}

var handlers = {
    addTecla: function(tecla){
        model.addTecla(tecla);
        view.displayTela();
    }
}
```

Por fim, sua função `displayTela` estava mexendo no `innerHTML` do `input`. É melhor usar `value` nesse caso:

```
var view = {
    displayTela: function(){
        var pTela = document.getElementById('tela');
        pTela.value = '';
        var tela = model.tela.join('');
        pTela.value = tela;
    }
}
```

Tem várias outras coisas que dá pra melhorar aí, mas por enquanto, já resolve o problema.
Bons estudos!